# Java - Deserialize entire json list from file

Tags: java, json, serialization

This comes from someone who doesn't really know Java.

I have a **.json** file that contains an array of objects. It is guaranteed that the file is formatted in a correct manner. Is there a simple way to deserialize the entire contents of that file into a `List<myObject>` (and then serialize it back as an array).

I saw all kinds of code that is more complex than it should, or treats each key in an individual manner, which is something that I don't really need.

Comment: @ΦXoce웃Пepeúpa that's the thing he doesn't.

Comment: I am not using one because I'm not familiar enough with the Java ecosystem to know where to look for one. I was asking for a library that will require as little boilerplate as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be:

1. in order to get rid off a lot of code and boilerplate use an already developed lib like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload) or similar,
2. take a look how you can model the list you are trying to read... and try to write a POJO Class ([online tools](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) can help you to do that)that represents the objects in the list.
3. try to serialize and deserialize the file's content and

the rest is just enjoy the results...

Comment: I know the steps (and I already have a data model), I stated what I need it for just in case someone wanted a bit of context. Jackson seems nice.